# How to separate data from the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, arp

I am trying to get the list of all the Computers connected on My network and I was able to do so.

But then I need to get the Hostanme of the Ip address which i have stored in the String format with some other data like mac address.

I have tried using json But was not able to get the List of Ip from the String. I just List of ip from the String so that using Foreach I can find the hostname on that specific in.

Here is the code:

```
  static void Main(String[] args)
  {
        Process arp = new Process();
        arp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        arp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        arp.StartInfo.FileName = "C://Windows//System32//cmd.exe";
        arp.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c arp -a";
        arp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        arp.Start();
        arp.WaitForExit();
        string output = arp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.WriteLine(data.Internet_Address);
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
}
```

And here is the Output :

[image]

Comment: Please add input and desired output in text form instead of image.

Comment: Where did this (**data.Internet_Address**) come from ???

Comment: Why can't you just get this information directly instead of calling command line tool and parsing its output?

Comment: I was trying to use Json But it Didn't work so (data.internet_Address) was from there My bad Sorry and thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the IPs using [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var matches1 = Regex.Matches(output, @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
```

As the first IP you may not need you can skip it.

```
for(int i=1; i < matches1.Count; i++)
     Console.WriteLine("IPs " + i + "\t" + matches1[i].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Adil it worked I was trying the hard using Json and it never hit me to use the Regex

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Generally one would use regular expression to parse such text. Alternatively you can get CSV library to parse similar format, or if this is just one-off case basic `String.Split` would do.

```
var byLine = output.Split('\n') // split into lines
   .Skip(1); // skip header
var ips = byLine.Select(s => s.Split(' ')[0]);
```

Notes:

- it is likely better to obtain information you are looking for by direct calls instead of calling command line tool
- local addresses generally don't have "hostnames". Windows machine name not necessary visible as DNS entry.